# Bad access exception using xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

I am getting "`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`"  when touch the button to call the button action.

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation TestViewController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
       self.title=@"IOS5 and Xoced 4.2";

        UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9,6,100,100)];
        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview: button];


    }
    return self;
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add" 
                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                target:self 
                                                                action:@selector(addAction)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

}
-(void)buttonAction
{
    printf("Hi i am in buttonAction method");

}

-(void)addAction
{
    printf("Hi i am in addAction method");

}
```

I used **ARC enbled** in this project.
When I touch the UIBarButtonItem or UIButton I am getting below error.

> TestXcode4[2470:207] -[__NSCFString addAction]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x6827b00

Please help me out of this.

Comment: declare UIBarButtonItem *addButton in your .h file and try again

Comment: You view controller is probably being released. How are you displaying this view controller?

Comment: @Maulik: Won't `addSubview:` and `rightButtonItem:` take ownership of the buttons when they are called?

Comment: Just try to replace -(void)buttonAction  by  -(IBAction) buttonAction :(id) sender, and also add ‘:’ in button action.

Comment: Pls include the code where you create and present this view controller.

Comment: @trojanfoe :ya true but I think it gets released before they take ownership !!! OR TestViewController get released !!!

Answer (score 1):

If you add this view controller to the window then you don't release that controller after addsubview call. Because window will not retain that view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I just disable the ARC in project setting. then it is working fine....